# Angular Material using ng-template for mat-list-items in mat-nav-list not applying styling

Tags: angular, angular-material

After updating to Angular v15 projecting our `mat-list-item`s into the `mat-nav-list` does no longer work as expected (hover effect is not working). See this code sample (or see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng5v1w-bbsdvs?file=src%2Fexample%2Flist-overview-example.html) example where I reproduced it):

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="items"></ng-container>
</mat-nav-list>

<ng-template #items>
  <a mat-list-item href="https://google.com"> google </a>
  <a mat-list-item href="https://angular.io"> angular </a>
</ng-template>
```

It's working as expected when I do not use content projection and it worked with Angular Material v14. Why does it no longer work?

**Edit:**
I reported it and they confirmed that it is a bug: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27608

Comment: A `mat-list-item` with content projection does not have `mat-mdc-list-item-interactive` class, that's why hover is not working. I assume content projection somehow affects _isNonInteractive property of `mat-nav-list`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I also realized this, I just don't know why it wouldn't.